# Where do I place Data Layer in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, database, data-layers

In .Net I usually create a separate class library and reference it in my project. This class library does all the select, insert and updates to the database. Or, I put classes or static  methods in the App_Code folder.

In iPhone Dev, where do I put this data layer in order to have a separation in code and logic. This layer, files, would be accessed by all the views, controllers that need data and want to write to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are talking about is the Model part of MVC.  I typically have a Class for each major table in my database that has all the necessary methods for handling that table.

So I have GeoNames.m/.h that interacts with my geonames table is sqlite and provides hydrate/dehydrate, query and misc helper methods.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to consider leveraging CoreData for your DAL. We implemented something very similar to what Carl described in our app, and although it works, you end up reinventing the CoreData wheel.